# how to resolve error time.clock() on odoo

Tags: python, odoo, python-3.8, odoo-14

I'm trying to install odoo on windows, this is Lastes steps .
git clone from site

pip install -r requirements.txt

python python odoo-bin -r odoo -w y2000 --addons-path=addons -d mydb
and then this error :

`

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
        import odoo
      File "C:\odoo\comunity\odoo\odoo\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
        from . import modules
      File "C:\odoo\comunity\odoo\odoo\modules\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
      File "C:\odoo\comunity\odoo\odoo\modules\graph.py", line 10, in <module>
        import odoo.tools as tools
      File "C:\odoo\comunity\odoo\odoo\tools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from . import cloc
      File "C:\odoo\comunity\odoo\odoo\tools\cloc.py", line 10, in <module>
        from odoo.tools.config import config
      File "C:\odoo\comunity\odoo\odoo\tools\config.py", line 18, in <module>
        from passlib.context import CryptContext
      File "C:\Users\Yazid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\passlib\context.py", line 15, in <module>
        from passlib.registry import get_crypt_handler, _validate_handler_name
      File "C:\Users\Yazid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\passlib\registry.py", line 12, in <module>
        from passlib.ifc import PasswordHash
      File "C:\Users\Yazid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\passlib\ifc.py", line 10, in <module>
        from passlib.utils.decor import deprecated_method
      File "C:\Users\Yazid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\passlib\utils\__init__.py", line 846, in <module>
        from time import clock as timer
    ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)
```

and here is part of code in line 846 as mentioned in error msg

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    print(sys.platform)
    # On Windows, the best timer is time.clock()
    from time import clock as timer
else:
    # On most other platforms the best timer is time.time()
    from time import time as timer

# legacy alias, will be removed in passlib 2.0
tick = timer
```

Answer (score 0):

from time import clock as timer

Since python 3.8 clock function from time module has been depreciated. I assume you have configured odoo 3.8 with your odoo. You need to configure odoo 3.7. You can create a new virtualenv using below command for python 3.7

path\to\python3.7 -m venv myvenv

Note: You might need to install python 3.7 separately.